# iphone programming objective-c : track user location in background questions

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, background, location

i have read that we can track user location in background. 
I have put in plist backgroundmodes array = location. 
I want to know if this only work with iphone 4 and 3gs?
Also , when the user change location while in background, does it triggle the DidFindPlacemark method?

finally is there a tutorial with "CODE" somewhere or a sample for this thing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for CLLocationManager, which is the GPS implementation.  It has no UI and runs in the background, but you don't invoke it from the PList, you implement a class.  Find the "LocateMe" example project for the code. This works in iPhone 3 on iOS 3.1.3, that's as far back as I have used it.